# Игры на SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, разработка-игр, spritekit

Охота начать писать игры под ios.  Посматриваю в сторону SpriteKit'a, т.к. есть небольшие знания языка. В общем вопрос: пишет ли кто нибудь на нем? За все время не встречал ни одного человека кто писал на спрайтКите. Складывается ощущение что этот фрейм не очень подходит под игры. Если есть у кого нибудь опыт со спрайтом, напишите свое мнение о нем.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть пара игрушек в App Store, написанных на Sprite Kit. Могу сказать, что из плюсов это то, что всё нативно. Из минусов - много кода. Раньше raywenderlich целые книжки выпускал по разработке на Sprite Kit, но с недавнего времени перестал из-за его непопулярности и перешел на Unity. Как-то так.